# android.permission.INTERNET not used yet able to send CGI calls through browser

Tags: android, security, android-intent, browser

I have not used the following permission in my app:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

However if i fire an intent with:

```
android.intent.action.VIEW
```

with a url that looked something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/collectUsersStuff?UsersSecretStuff=hisSecret
```

it will open a prompt to open chrome to connect to the webserver.   So my point is even without the INTERNET permissions from my apps manifest i can get the authority to send from another app who handles network calls. Is there anyway to assure the user that my app will not take advantage of this flaw ?

Comment: So what is the issue? That standard browsers can view webpages and that you can open browsers from your app? I'm afraid that isn't a bug.

Comment: I think the internet connection would not be used by your app, but the activity launched by your app. Therefore the internet permission is not required. What do you mean by flaw ? Please clarify.

Comment: The technical explanation is: the browser that loads the URL has the permission `android.permission.INTERNET`. So there is actually no violation of permissions per se. Indirectly that may be perceived as a security flaw, I get your point. As far as I know there is nothing to prevent that scenario from happening. But whatever "hisSecret" is, it will most likely require some sensitive permissions which should raise concerns on installation. Furthermore, the browser would visibly open, the URL would be visible too. Such an odd behavior would get an app flagged pretty quickly, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a flaw. The INTERNET permission is allowing *your* app to access network sites. When you call the VIEW intent, you are telling a *different* app to open the site. Those apps have the INTERNET permission, which is why this works fine.

Comment: How do you guys not see the security flaw here.  An app that has declared to the user it does not send out on the internet gets downloaded.  But then it magically creates a web server call that a browser handles.  We have now gotten away with telling the user our app does not make network calls but really we just did through the browser.  But i also see where your coming from that the browser has the permission not my app.  For me a call to any app that uses the INTERNET permission from within a app that does not have it should not be allowed.

Comment: @j2emanue Ah, I see what you mean now. Essentially, you're saying that if an app tells the user's selected default browser to go to go to a URL that will cause it to automatically download malware (for example), this could happen without the user ever getting a prompt. Correct?

Comment: @j2emanue That kind of communication would be one-sided only and is restricted through the maximum URL length that may be imposed by the chosen browser and the web server that receives the URL. It is a possible exploit and you may want to blog about it and show some proof of concept. However, the browser would visibly open and display a suspicious looking URL. It would do its thing in plain sight. I think malicious app developers do not care about people who are security conscious. The vast majority of users install apps no matter what permissions they demand.